# Undefined std_logic_vector size parameter in procedure

Tags: fpga, vhdl, simulation, hdl

I have written into a procedure the behavior of a simple SPI transaction that I use in my testbenches to make things easier to write and read.
Is there a way to make this procedure as generic as possible by not mentioning the size of the vector `data` given as a parameter? Or maybe add a size parameter as an integer?

Here's the procedure I'm using so far. For now I have one procedure declaration for each vector size I want to transfer.

```
procedure spi_transfer_3B(data : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0)) is 
variable bitCnt : integer := data'length-1;
begin
    spi_clk <= '0';
    spi_mosi <= 'Z';
    spi_ss <= '0';
    wait until rising_edge(clk);

    for i in 2*data'length-1 downto 0 loop
        wait for SPI_CLK_PERIOD/2;
        spi_clk <= not spi_clk;
        if spi_clk = '0' then
            spi_mosi <= data(bitCnt);
            bitCnt := bitCnt -1;
        end if;
    end loop;

    spi_clk <= '0';
    wait until rising_edge(clk);
    spi_ss <= '1';
    spi_mosi <= 'Z';
end spi_transfer_3B;
```

What do you think?

Comment: Have you tried removing the range specification in the first line and seeing if it works for different widths of `data`?

Comment: Yes, it is somewhat working, but not really. `spi_transfer(x"45")` gives me `"A2"` after deserializing the MOSI line. But it is probably the way to go, I'm trying to find the tweaking needed here

Comment: Oh... `0x45 = 0b01000101` and `0xA2 = 0b10100010`. It's inverted, okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work. I was confused because not mentioning `x downto x` coded the vector LSB first instead of MSB first as intended in my first snippet of code. It is that easy.

```
procedure spi_transfer(data : std_logic_vector) is 
variable bitCnt : integer := 0;
begin
    spi_clk <= '0';
    spi_mosi <= 'Z';
    spi_ss <= '0';
    wait until rising_edge(clk);

    for i in data'range loop
       wait for SPI_CLK_PERIOD/2;
       spi_clk <= '1';
       spi_mosi <= data(i);
       wait for SPI_CLK_PERIOD/2;
       spi_clk <= '0';
    end loop;

    spi_clk <= '0';
    wait until rising_edge(clk);
    spi_ss <= '1';
    spi_mosi <= 'Z';
end spi_transfer;
```

Comment: You can simplify and eliminate bitCnt to i, by reversing the range of the loop `for i in data'range loop ...` (or reverse_range as appropriate), and a second `wait` and `spi_clk` assignment, instead of doubling the range and using the `if` statement.

Comment: Good call, it looks better this way. I'm editing my answer with your simplification. Thanks!

Comment: .... closer ... but now you can (and probably must!) eliminate the "if" too, and you can explicitly set spi_clk to '0' or '1' in each assignment.

Comment: Edited again, thanks! I didn't read your first comment carefully enough, my bad